# The microcanonical ensemble surface distribution function

Tags: statistical-mechanics

on page 58 of the book "the principles of statistical mechanics" by Richard C. Tolman, there refers to a formula for the surface density of distribution in microcanonical ensemble, which is:
[image]

The above density is a function of phase point E, p and q. Although distribution function for a microcanonical ensemble must be a function of only the energy of phase points. On the other hand, it may change with time due to not depending only on integrals of the motion.

What's wrong in my statements?

Comment: Hello welcome to PSE. Are you asking where does that formula come from? PS you can use Mathjax for equations (which is usually appreciated and preferred versus figures)

Comment: @lcv Thanks for your reply. Yes, I want to know where that formula comes from. I would certainly use Mathjax later on. I'm afraid that I was somehow lazy about writing above formula with Mathjax for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microcanonical distribution is the uniform distribution on the surface $H(p,q)=E_0$. You can write it as

$$
\rho(p,q) = C \delta (H(p,q) - E_0)
$$

where $C$ is a normalization constant such that $\int dp dq \rho (p,q) =1$ and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta.

You can think that the phase space is foliated by energy surfaces given by $H(p,q)= E$ for various energies $E$ where $E$ varies appropriately. Under (very general) suitable conditions, instead of integrating over $(p,q)$ we can also integrate over different energies $E$ and for each energy we integrate over the surface $H(p,q)= E$.  So we can change variables from $(p,q)$ to $(S,E)$ where $S$ are variables on the surface $H(p,q)= E$. The factor $1/\Vert \nabla H \Vert$ is essentially the Jacobian of the transformation.
Such formula is called [coarea formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formulahttps://) in math.

Now, say we want to compute the microcanonic expectation value of a certain function $f$. Performing this change of variables we obtain

\begin{align}
\langle f\rangle_{MC} &= C \int dp dq \delta (H(p,q)-E_0) f(p,q) \\
& = C \int dE \int \frac{dS}{\Vert \nabla H \Vert} \delta (H(p,q)-E_0) f(S,E) \\
& = C \int_{H=E_0} \frac{dS}{\Vert \nabla H \Vert}  f(S,E_0). 
\end{align}

So we see that, on the surface $H(p,q)= E_0$ the microcanonic distribution is

$$
\frac{C }{\Vert \nabla H \Vert}.
$$

Outside of such surface the distribution is zero.

To understand where the factor $1/\Vert \nabla H \Vert$ arises from, you can look at the one-dimensional case $(p,q)=x$, $H(x)=E_0$ . When you change variable from $x$ to $y=H(x)$ the Jacobian is precisely
$1/\vert \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \vert$, i.e.

\begin{align}
& \int dx f(x) \delta (H(x)-E_0)  \\
&= \int \frac{dy}{\vert \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \vert} f(x(y)) \delta (y-E_0) \\
&= \frac{f(x(E_0))}{\vert \frac{\partial H (x_0)}{\partial x} \vert} .
\end{align}

Coming to your statements, a distribution function is a function of $(p,q)$. The microcanonic one is zero outside the surface $H=E_0$. On the surface $H=E_0$ you can pick the $2n-1$ variables $S$ to specify a point and a non-zero value of $\rho$.